# Online Many-to-one Matching

Tags: algorithms, matching, online-algorithms

### Offline Problem

> I have a graph $\mathcal{G} = (\mathcal{D} \cup \mathcal{A},
> \mathcal{E})$. Each edge $e \in \mathcal{E}$ between the two vertex
>   sets $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ has an associated weight $w_e$.
>   Also, each vertex in $\mathcal{A}$ has a quota $Q$ i.e. each vertex in
>   $\mathcal{A}$ can match with at most $Q$ vertices in $\mathcal{D}$. I
>   need to find a matching between $\mathcal{D}$ and $\mathcal{A}$, such
>   that the sum of weights is maximized.

### Online Version

> The vertices $\mathcal{D}$ arrive one-by-one and upon arrival, all the
>   corresponding weights to the vertex set $\mathcal{A}$ is revealed. On
>   each arrival, I need to match the vertex in  $\mathcal{D}$ with a
>   vertex in $\mathcal{A}$, which cannot later be revoked. Again, note
>   that each vertex in  $\mathcal{A}$ can be matched $Q$ times.

### What I thought

Splitting approach: Split each vertex in $\mathcal{A}$ into $Q$ vertices such that:

- The weights from a vertex in $\mathcal{D}$ is duplicated for each of the $Q$ vertices.
- While matching, any one of the $Q$ vertices with same weights is chosen arbitrarily.

Thus, it turns into a one-to-one matching problem.

From this [paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397594900426), the online version of such a problem can be solved with an algorithm with a competitive ratio of $2n-1$ where $n$ is the number of vertices. However, this splitting approach leads to an increase in the size of $n$ i.e. $n = |\mathcal{A}| Q + |\mathcal{D}|$, which leads to poor performance if quota $Q$ is large.

---

**Is there a better alternative approach?**
I will be grateful anyone can point me towards any relevant resources.